Image by a Time-Invariant Linear System of a real input - is it real also?
Is the output image by a Time-Invariant Linear System of a real input, also real? How does one prove it?
I'd like to know it because I want to prove sinusoidal fidelity from the fact that $e^{i\omega t}$ are eigenvalues of TILS.
So from the known fact: $H(e^{i\omega t})=A e^{i\omega t}$ (where $H$ is the TILS and $A\in \mathbb C$), I'd like to take real part of these.
And according to this answer (from math.stackexchange) we need two things to apply $\mathfrak {Re} $ without caution: first, that the real inputs are $H$- invariant (and of course that the same goes for imaginary inputs). Second, that the set of all imputs is a direct sum of a set of real inputs and a set of imaginary inputs.
Second point is trivial.
Now, for first point, I can't find any reference on internet about the image of real inputs.

I assume you know that the input-output relation of an LTI system is given by the convolution of the input with the system's impulse response. If both the input and the impulse response are real, then the output must also be real.

Yes I saw that LTI is modelled by a convolution. But I don't get why the impulse response would be real. Is it always the case? I know that the impulse response is the response to a unit dirac function. I understand that this dirac function (in time) is real, but why would be its response real?

Complex output could only come from either a complex input or a complex-valued system (which has two outputs, one for the real part and one for the imaginary part). Every system you can build is real-valued. A complex-valued system is just a unified mathematical description of two related (real-valued) systems.

Not to be a nag, but the standard abbreviation for a Linear Time Invariant system is LTI. The main usage of TILS appears to be Tumor-infiltrating lymphocytes, which is hopefully not what we are talking about here.

@Hilmar I didn't know about that other meaning. Well, I'm new to this (plus, I saw another usage here in SE of the wrong acronym). I'll use "LTI" from now on.

@niobium: Perfectly understandable and  no problem. If in doubt, google it :-). The first sentence on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_time-invariant_system  calls it LTI

Both signals and systems can be real or complex (at least in the mathematically sense). If the system is LTI AND real, than the response to a real signal will also be real. If either one is complex, than the output will generally also be complex, but of course there are exceptions where the imaginary part cancels and the output is real.
We've had some interesting philosophical discussions around the physical interpretation of complex signals as (at least according to me) they don't exist in the real world. An easy resolution is to simply define a complex signal to be a pair of real signals and calling one the real part and the other one the imaginary part. That's very useful in some cases and non-sensical in others, but it certainly can be a useful approach.
